# SugarCRM REST API v11 filtering records

Tags: rest, api, sugarcrm

I am using postman application to do a SugarCRM POST request, following is the request

```
https://{site_url}/rest/v11/{module_name}/filter?filter=[{"$is_null"="logoutdttime"}]&fields=name,username,logoutdttime&order_by=date_entered&max_num=10
```

I am getting the error

```
{
    "error": "invalid_parameter",
    "error_message": "Unexpected filter type string."
}
```

but when I remove the filter, I get the response

```
https://{site_url}/rest/v11/{module_name}/filter?fields=name,username,logoutdttime&order_by=date_entered&max_num=10
```

what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

The filter is defined as array via the key and in an assoc array style rather than json. That's weird, but that's how it works in Sugar Query-String params.

Try:

```
https://{site_url}/rest/v11/{module_name}/filter?filter[0][$is_null]=logoutdttime&fields=name,username,logoutdttime&order_by=date_entered&max_num=10
```

Alternatively you can use the `POST /filter` endpoint instead of `GET`.
Then you can pass all params in the request body as json.

PS: Also are you sure you mean `$is_null` and not `$empty`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply on this, its not working, it gives an error
{
    "error": "invalid_parameter",
    "error_message": "Unknown field $is_null"
}
doesn't work with $empty either

Comment: As I hinted in my "PS:" back then, you probably want to use `$empty` instead of `$is_null`, as the latter does not actually exist (as far as I know).

Comment: Sorry, I was passing the filters the wrong way (in the Params section). I was supposed to pass it in the Body section by selecting "raw" radio button. By the way do you know how to use refresh token after original authentication token expires? They have not provided a example in support.sugarcrm.com

Comment: I'm glad to hear you could solve it :) Regarding refresh-tokens: I'd have to look it up myself. Please make a new question for this and I'll answer it in the next days (if nobody is faster) :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I could find the documentation on refreshing tokens, its specified [here in their documentation](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_9.0/Integration/Web_Services/REST_API/Endpoints/oauth2token_POST/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
filter[0][name][$starts]=any text
```

Document:
https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_12.0/Integration/Web_Services/REST_API/Endpoints/Accountsrecordlinklink_namefilter_GET/